# Instalación Jenkins contraseña

Tags: jenkins

Buenas a la hora de instalar jenkins me pide unas claves.
Pensaba que eran las claves de Windows, pero no me funcionan, y tampoco las de Jenkins que ya tengo en otra PC.
Alguien puede ayudarme lo agradezco.
Mi usuario es adminstrador, claro.
GRacias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si entiendes inglés, checa esta respuesta del sitio en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410442/jenkins-installation-windows-10-service-logon-credentials

Comment: @BaruchSpinoza no te le mides a traducirla y ponerla como respuesta?

Comment: @JVT pero si es claro que ese paso que estás haciendo es para crear el servicio del sistema para arrancar y parar Jenkins como servicio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario que asignes a tu usuario el permiso de "Iniciar sesión como servicio. Este permiso de inicio de sesión aplica estrictamente a la computadora local y debe ser concedida en las políticas de seguridad locales.

Lleva a cabo los siguientes pasos para editar las políticas de seguridad en tu computadora si quieres definir el permiso de "Iniciar de sesión como servicio".

- Inicia sesión en la computadora con privilegios de administrador
- Abre las "Herramientas administrativas" y luego "Directiva de seguridad local"
- Expande "Directiva local" y da click en "Asignación de derechos de usuario"
- En el panel de la derecha, da click derecho a "Iniciar sesión como servicio" y selecciona "Propiedades".
- Da click al botón "Agregar usuario o grupo".
- En el diálogo "Seleccionar usuarios o grupos", encuentra al usuario que desees ingresar y luego da click en "Aceptar".
- Da click en "Aceptar" también en la ventana "Asignación de derechos de usuario" para guardar los cambios.

Reinicia tu computadora y luego intenta instalar Jenkins nuevamente con el usuario y contraseña asignados.

Comment: De momento no consigo encontrar esas opciones en mi equipo, aunque he comprobado que estoy como adminstrador. Seguire intentadolo pero en Herramientas administrativas no me aparece Directiva de seguridad local

Comment: Comprendo, hazme saber si puedo ayudar en algo más.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente fui capaz de realizar la configuración, pero quiero dejar unas notas para los que tengan este problema, ya que a configuración no fue fácil.
En primer lugar, la respuesta de Baruch era correcta, pero si tienes windows 10 home no se puede hacer. Es necesario en primer lugar instalar gpedit para poder acceder a la configuración de Directivas de seguridad local.
https://www.xataka.com/basics/como-usar-el-editor-de-directivas-de-grupo-local-gpedit-msc-si-tu-windows-no-lo-trae
Una vez realizado ejecutas gpedit.msc y  realizas los pasos como se describen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]